# How to delete duplicate rows based on one column in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Say I have column A, B and Date, and I want all rows which are duplicated in A to be removed, while keeping the one with the most recent Date. How would I do this?

I have looked at many other solutions but none seem to work for my case.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: please give some data sample and expected result

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
DELETE FROM YourTable USING 
  (SELECT colA, MAX(Date) maxDate
   FROM YourTable
   GROUP BY colA
  ) AS Keep 
WHERE Keep.maxDate <> YourTable.Date
AND Keep.ColA = YourTable.ColA
```

Answer (score 0):

will stay:

```
t=# with sample(a,b,dat) as (values(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,2,3),(2,2,4))
, comparison as (select *,max(dat) over (partition by a) from sample)
select * 
from comparison
where dat = max;
 a | b | dat | max 
---+---+-----+-----
 1 | 2 |   3 |   3
 2 | 2 |   4 |   4
(2 rows)
```

and thus to be deleted:

```
t=# with sample(a,b,dat) as (values(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,2,3),(2,2,4))
, comparison as (select *,max(dat) over (partition by a) from sample)
delete 
from comparison
where dat <> max
returning *;
 a | b | dat | max 
---+---+-----+-----
 1 | 1 |   1 |   3
 1 | 1 |   2 |   3
 2 | 2 |   3 |   4
(3 rows)
```

of course instead of comparison you should name your table

Comment: thanks for answer, one question, what does the "t=#" mean?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING it's a database name `t` and `#` for superuser